# Counting and Totals

Tags: php, counting

I have a list of numbers that are inputted by users. I want to count them and get:

1. Subtotals for each number (only numbers possible are `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`), and
2. a total of all inputted numbers.

See:

```
// Outputs the numbers , " 1 4 1 1 5  " 
// for example (no commas, order is as inputed by user)
echo $a;
```

**#1:**

```
if ($a == "1"){
    $b++;

    // Outputs the actual count but in steps, 
    // say there are 3 "1" then it outputs: 1 2 3 , 
    // but I only want the 3. 
    echo $b;
}
```

How can I overwrite the incremented variable? Then I kind of have what I want or am I wrong. Is there a better/cleaner approach?

**#2:**

```
// outputs only a bunch of 11111 
// (the right amount if i add them up)
echo count($a);

// outputs also a bunch of 111111
print strlen($a);
```

Any other way to count and get a total (not a sum, a total of inputted numbers)?

I've been trying to figure this out for days. Obviously, I am a beginner and I would love to understand. I have checked about 5 php books and the php online manual.  I would appreciate if anyone could lead me in the right direction. Please :)

Comment: This: `$a == "1"` is equivalent to this: `$a == 1`, due to PHP's [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). There is no reason to add comments around a number with that type of comparison, since you're just turning it into a string with a number to compare to another number/string that will be converted as well; PHP will do the comparison the same with or without the quotes in this case. However, using `$a === "1"` would first check the variable's type, then compare, which would give you a different result if `$a` were not a string value.

Comment: See: http://codepad.org/GRDW18f2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do what you are requesting. It splits the numbers into an array, uses array_sum to count up all the elements and then uses the size of the array to count the total number of elements. It also uses trim, to clean up any whitespace a user may have entered.

```
$split_numbers = explode(' ',trim($a));
$total_added = array_sum($split_numbers);
$total_numbers = sizeof($split_numbers);
```

You can see this code in action [here](http://codepad.org/1L7vmOfz).

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, the sizeof() and count() come back as 1111 and explode() and then array_sum() give me "Array Total numbers: 1" instead of the numbers and the total:3

Comment: I tested your code in a empty file and it works great. But not on mine. Also, my variable $a is part of an array, it comes from an explode. 

$data = explode(' ',($abc));

$a = $data[1];